# Getting alert of telerik ui for asp.net mvc requires nuget package manager 2.8 or later

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

For Visual studio 2013, when I try to create a new project, I get this alert message "Telerik UI for ASP.Net requires NuGet Package Manager 2.8.50126.400 or later". 
I am not understanding what it is trying to say and unable to create my project and start my work.
In the menu bar in Visual Studio, I have one menu option named "TELERIK", may be it is related to that but not getting the exact solution to this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the NuGet package manager that is installed inside your Visual Studio. You can download the latest version for VS 2013 from here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2013 or you can go Tools > Extensions and Updates and update it from there.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I am able to add a new project.